# Django bulk_create IntegrityError (Duplicate entry) with UUID primary_key

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to save a huge amount of objects in a model, so I decided to use bulk_create by this way:

```
while True:
    batch = list(islice(records, 100))
    if not batch:
        break
    models.Record.objects.bulk_create(batch, batch_size)
```

But I get this error when I add the second batch of 100:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '165ab345f2ad47bbb2072ab7b3e8023f' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

This is the model if it helps you:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code is returning the same slice every time, so you get the integrity error because you've already inserted that particular record. The current code is starting from the same starting location.  Try using standard python slicing instead.

```
record_list = []
for record in records:
    if len(record_list) % 100 == 0:
        models.Record.objects.bulk_create(record_list, len(record_list))
        record_list = []
    else:
        record_list.append(record)
```

According to `islice` documentation, your current code is returning all but the first 100 elements of your records as a single slice .  See more here, https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't think about it... Thank you!